# When i use search by symbols i have a problem, why get request send by any symbols?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
searchEmployee(e) {
    const {entityType} = this.state;
    const searchText = this.searchInput.value;

    if (e.target.value !== '' && searchText.length !== 0) {
        this.drop.hide();

        if (searchText.length > 3) {
            this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
                this.setState({
                    showSearchLoader: true,
                    result: [],
                    resultCounts: [],
                    hasMoreItems: false,
                    searchResultsEmpty: false,
                    entityType: 10,
                    searchAll: true
                });

                this.getResults(searchText, entityType, this.searchResultsCount, 0, false);
            }, 1000);
        }
    }

}

getResults(searchText, entityType, searchResultsCount, offset, concat = true) {
    const {result: stateResult} = this.state;

    searchGlobal(searchText, entityType, searchResultsCount, offset).then(({result, resultCounts}) => {
        this.setState({
            result: concat ? _.concat(stateResult, result) : result,
            resultCounts,
            offset: offset,
            hasMoreItems: result.length >= 8,
            showSearchLoader: false,
            searchResultsEmpty: !result.length
        });

        this.searchInput.focus();
        setTimeout(() => this.drop.show(), 400);
    }).catch(handleErrorResponse);
}
```

[get request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hs346.png)
When i print in timeout time two or more symbols i have - two or more request! 
And this request back to me error!
It turns out from one that returns data from another avatar, how to make such a request that he would not send each character but only what will be printed at the end

Comment: How to send get by time? exp they have 3 sec for input name and when they input all name = send only all name like john??? now i have request like j and jo and joh and john !

Comment: as far as i can see if you are trying to limit the requests sent to server ? if so then on each call you will have to clear the previous timeout, before setting the new one, as it will just delay the get request no cancel